# iPhone: record output sounds without mic

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, audio, audio-recording

I am writing an app which needs to record output sounds without microphone.
For example: If I have two sound files, first.mp3 and second.mp3, I want to press record button, then press playfirst button, then playsecond button then stoprecordbutton. After this i should have third.mp3 which includes recorded sounds of frst and second.
Is it possible?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: So you need to mix the 2 sound files? You need them merged head-to-tail or one over another, like adding drums to some voice sound?

Comment: no i don't need to merge or mix it. i just need to record application's output sound without mic. if i play first.mp3, wait 2.5 secs and then play second.mp3 i should get third.mp3 included first.mp3 silent for 2.5sec and second.mp3.

Comment: @TeodorCarstea - Exactly, and why do you need to do this via recording versus just merging them.  Is it because you wish to try and understand the noise qualities of the output amp or DAC?

Comment: @trumpetlicks, I agree. He could merge them with a 2.5 seconds silent sound file in the middle.

Comment: @TeodorCarstea - Better yet, he could simply zero fill as long as he wishes. He could even allow his users to decide how long to blank in between :-)

Comment: tnx guys for you reply.
i am making app like dj app and i dont know how much silience should be between 2 sounds. thats why i want to record output sounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im pretty sure that this is NOT possible on the device without first letting the sound escape the device.

In order for what you want to be possible, the Hardware engineers at apple would have had to put an analog multiplexor with the output facing the recode input interface with (at least) 2 inputs, one which is the actual microphone that touches the outside world, and the other would be the output of the speaker DAC.  I just dont think this is the way they designed the hardware.

How it would have to be:

[image]

How the most likely did it!!!

[image]

Comment: Ok. thanks for knowing it.
it seems i have to mix 2 sounds, add second to the end of the first.
can you give me the example how to do that?
i have 2 mp3 files. first.mp3 and second.mp3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851123/join-multiple-audio-files-into-one or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628924/ios-combine-concatenate-multiple-audio-files or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644046/how-to-concatenate-2-or-3-audio-files-in-ios  Seems you have asked this question before!

Comment: i saw that questions already but they didn't help me :( i still can't do that.
i need 1 sample. can u help me?